# Espresso, RecyclerView and ComposeView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm using Espresso to test a screen with a RecyclerView and a ComposeView in the ViewHolder. **I want to click on a particular Composable inside the RecyclerView**
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried launching the test with `@get:Rule val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()` and assert your composable with that rule? Like `composeRule.onNodeWithText(xxx).assertIsDisplayed()`

Comment: Yes I have tried that

Comment: if you use `rule` in Espresso testing like this `ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity>(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))`, you need to use `@get:Rule(order = ) var composeRule = createEmptyComposeRule()` in the test

Comment: I`m also looking for a way to test compose view in the RecyclerView. Did you find a solution  for  this @AryeeteySolomonAryeetey ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to interract with composables inside view-based UI, you need to add `ComposeTestRule` into your UI test as below:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createEmptyComposeRule()
```

Now you can use it to identify particular composable and perform action on it:

```
composeTestRule.onNode(hasText("Text inside compose view")).performClick()
```

Another way to identify particular composable is by tag, which you need to set first on the composable itself:

```
Text(
    text = "Some text",
    modifier = Modifier.testTag("textTag")
)
```

Then in your test:

```
composeTestRule.onNode(hasTestTag("textTag")).assertIsDisplayed()
```

Following dependencies are needed for compose test rules:

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version")
```